# Django Auth fails, even if user/pass exist in DB

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Given I have this create user view

```
class UserView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            encrypted_username_hex = data.get('username', None)
            encrypted_password_hex = data.get('password', None)
            phone_number = data.get('phone_number', None)
            email = data.get('email', None)

            missing_fields = [field for field in ['username', 'password', 'email'] if data.get(field) is None]
            if missing_fields:
                return JsonResponse({"error": f"Missing required field(s): {', '.join(missing_fields)}"}, status=400)

            session_id = request.session.session_key
            print("user create ses", session_id)
            private_key_pem, _ = RSAKeyManager.get_keys(session_id)
            if not private_key_pem:
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid session or RSA keys not found"}, status=404)
            print("private key", private_key_pem)
            username = RSAHandler.decrypt_from_hex(private_key_pem, encrypted_username_hex)
            password = RSAHandler.decrypt_from_hex(private_key_pem, encrypted_password_hex)

            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password,
                                                  phone_number=phone_number)

            return JsonResponse({"user": user.email, "phone_number": user.phone_number}, status=201)

        except IntegrityError as e:
            if 'username' in str(e):
                return JsonResponse({"error": "This username is already taken."}, status=400)
            elif 'email' in str(e):
                return JsonResponse({"error": "This email is already in use."}, status=400)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": "There was an error with your request."}, status=400)

        except ValidationError as e:
            return JsonResponse({"error": str(e.messages[0])}, status=400)

        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return JsonResponse({"error": "Internal server error."}, status=500)
```

And this custom user model:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, phone_number=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, phone_number=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, phone_number=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))

        return self.create_user(username, email, password, phone_number, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', "password"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    # Add related_name to groups and user_permissions fields
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.'),
        related_name="custom_user_set",  # Changed related_name
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name="custom_user_set",  # Changed related_name
        related_query_name="user",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

And this login view:

```
class LoginView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            email = data.get('email', None)
            encrypted_password_hex = data.get('password', None)
            session_id = request.session.session_key

            private_key_pem, _ = RSAKeyManager.get_keys(session_id)
            print(session_id)
            password = RSAHandler.decrypt_from_hex(private_key_pem, encrypted_password_hex)
            print(email)
            print(password)
            # Authenticating the user
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            user = authenticate(username='tes321t@gm3ail.com', password='test')

            print("user", user)
            if user is not None:
                # User is authenticated, now generate a JWT token
                payload = {
                    'session_id': request.session.session_key,
                    'username': user.username,
                }
                jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

                return JsonResponse({"token": jwt_token, "user": user.username}, status=200)
            else:
                # Authentication failed
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid credentials"}, status=401)

        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({"error": str(e)}, status=500)
```

I cannot manage to auth,

I tried manually to specify user/pass but still, user is always none:

```
user = authenticate(username='tes321t@gm3ail.com', password='test')
```

The user exists in the db, the password is corretly hashed it seems, the password is the same (in plain text) not sure what I m doing wrong at this point :(

Flow is as such ->

1. Client requests RSA pub key and ses id
2. Client sends user/create data as: encrypted password, pain text email and other fields, backend stores email and plain text hashed password(rsa decrypted) using django `set_password`
3. Client requests user/login with email and rsa_encrypted_password, backend decrypts password to plain text, and calls django authenticate with plain text email/password)

Even with  hardcoded data, auth still fails:

```
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            random_string = str(uuid.uuid4())[:4]
            from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

            CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=random_string, email=random_string, password='test',
                                                  phone_number='test')
            user = authenticate(request, email=random_string, password='test')
            print(user)
            return JsonResponse({"user": user})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'er': str(e)})
```

For this line i use username instead of email aswell
            `user = authenticate(request, username=random_string, password='test')`, same outcome, returns None

Manually checking user password (for hardcoded example, works)

```
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=random_string)

            print("check pass", check_password('test', user.password))
```

check_password, returns True

Comment: Since you perform hashing *manually* first (i.e. `password = RSAHandler.decrypt_from_hex(private_key_pem, encrypted_password_hex)`, you will need to do that too for the **`username`/`email` as well.

Comment: Well I send password rsa encrypted but email is in plain text, I pass plain text emai/password to django authenticate method
Did I somehow missed something with the user mode customization?

Comment: so when creating you send the username encrypted, when you login, you don't?

Comment: Username is encrypted, yes (its old behavior, wanna move login to email, which is sent in plain text), but in DB, I also store username as plain text, its just that I send it over HTTP(S) encrypted

Comment: Basically login happens with email and password (not username) so we can ignore all together really, in my custom user model, I do tell django to use email field as login username `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` or  atleast its what I understood from docs

Comment: Why are you encrypting when sending the username / password anyway? Can't you leave that upto the TLS setup of your website?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, that was my idea as well. Multilayer encryption often does not add (much) to the system https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18104/53798 and therefore is often more a pain than a gain.

Comment: I could, but read its just extra caution, and why not really, but the problem is Auth dosen't work regardless, I just hardcoded user.create and authenticate with plain text creds, it still dosen't work, so the problem is definitelly with the user custom model imo

I'll update the post with the hardcoded  stuff

Comment: You say "same outcome" but **what** is the outcome? What output do you get?

Comment: So `user = authenticate(request, email=random_string, password='test')` returns None.

Sorry for the confusion, will update in post body also

Comment: Manually checking user.password using `django.hashers.check_passwords`, returns `true`, so it is clear that its not a user/pass match but a authenticate -> custom user model problem. Added code example in the post

Comment: What is the value of your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting?

Comment: I haven't set up anything for `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, its default I assume.
I'll give it a quick read on google/docs

Comment: Yup so found out for custom user models i gotta  specify it for auth, did `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.CustomUser'` and it works now properly, thank you very much!

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem do we have a good canonical for problems with setting up custom user models anywhere? This has been asked quite a few times but I can't seem to find any good duplicate targets.